# Losing content of TThreadList

Tags: multithreading, delphi, pascal

I got the problem, that my content of my TThreadList seems to get lost in my Thread.

I create following variable in my "PConnect" Class:

```
var mCustomfunctionCallbackThread: CustomfunctionCallbackThread;
```

And a **global** variable like following:

```
var mCustomfunctionCallbackThreadList: TThreadList;
```

Now I'm filling this variable in my "PConnect" Class like following:

```
function PConnect.callCustomfunction(plugin, method: PAnsiChar; param :CustomParam; callback: ICustomfunctionCallback; callId: PAnsiChar): integer;
var paramName: PAnsiChar;
var id: PAnsiChar;
var error: integer;
var callbackList: TList;
var customfunctionCallback : ^CustomfunctionCallbackObject;
begin
     callbackList:= mCustomfunctionCallbackThreadList.LockList;

     new (customfunctionCallback);
     customfunctionCallback.callId:= id;
     customfunctionCallback.callbackMethod:= callback;
     callbackList.Add(customfunctionCallback);

     mCustomfunctionCallbackThreadList.UnlockList;
     exit(0);
end;
```

Following function will be called, after I a Callback received. This Function should append the other missing data to the TThreadList entry and start a Thread after that:

```
procedure PConnect.customfunctionCallbackReceived(param :CustomParam; callId: PAnsiChar; error: integer);
var customfunctionCallbackList: TList;
var it: TListEnumerator;
var callbackObject: ^CustomfunctionCallbackObject;
begin
    customfunctionCallbackList:= mCustomfunctionCallbackThreadList.LockList;
    it:= customfunctionCallbackList.GetEnumerator;
    while(it.MoveNext) do
    begin
        callbackObject:= it.GetCurrent;
        if strcomp(callbackObject.callId,callId) = 0 then
        begin
            callbackObject.param:= param;
            callbackObject.error:= error;
            break;
        end;
    end;
    mCustomfunctionCallbackThreadList.UnlockList;
    mCustomfunctionCallbackThread.Start();
end;
```

The Execute method of the Thread should get the content of the TThreadList and call a function with that parameters.

```
procedure CustomfunctionCallbackThread.Execute;
var callback: ICustomfunctionCallback;
var customfunctionCallbackList: TList;
var it: TListEnumerator;
var callbackObject: ^CustomfunctionCallbackObject;
var param: CustomParam;
var callId: PAnsiChar;
var error: Integer;
begin
    customfunctionCallbackList:= mCustomfunctionCallbackThreadList.LockList;
    it:= customfunctionCallbackList.GetEnumerator;
    while(it.MoveNext) do
    begin
        callbackObject:= it.GetCurrent;
        if callbackObject.error <> NULL then
        begin
            callback:= callbackObject.callbackMethod;
            param:= callbackObject.param;
            error:= callbackObject.error;
            callId:= callbackObject.callId;

            callback.callCustomfunctionCallback(param, callId, error);
            customfunctionCallbackList.Remove(callbackObject);
            break;
        end;
    end;
    mCustomfunctionCallbackThreadList.UnlockList;
end;
```

And heres the Problem, the following variables just got rubbish or Null pointer:

```
param:= callbackObject.param;
error:= callbackObject.error;
callId:= callbackObject.callId;
```

I hope it was enough described :)

I would be happy about some help :)

Comment: Daniel, why are you mixing old TP-style objects with real class instances, why are you using PAnsiChar where a string would be more useful, why do you repeat the `var` keyword for each variable? This is rather untypical for Delphi. Did you come from another language?

Comment: @Rudy Why do you think there are TP objects here. It looks like a record to me. The use of `New` is to heap allocate a record and put in the list.

Comment: @David: Perhaps because the item being `New`ed is declared as `^CustomfunctionCallbackObject;` (note the last six characters). Sure looks like an object and not a record to me as well.

Comment: @Ken The class is named `PConnect` and every local variable is preceeded by `var`. So perhaps you are reading too much into naming. Also I frequently name things *object* that are not TP objects. An object is simply an instance of a class. Or indeed an instance of a type. I'd say that an instance of a record was an object. The fact that the type has reference or value semantics is beside the point.

Comment: @David: You're the one who asked Rudy why he thought TP objects were involved. I pointed out a reason to suspect that: `^CustomfunctionCallbackObject` and `new(customFunctionCallBack)` suggested that to me as well.

Comment: @David: sure, could be records too, but something called BlaBlaObject is probably an object and not a record, as Ken said. Fact is that we don't know, but it **looks** suspicious to me and that is why I asked.

Comment: Daniel, please show your `CustomfunctionCallbackObject` type declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

```
customfunctionCallback.callId:= id
```

the variable `id` has not been initialised. Which means that when you later check

```
strcomp(callbackObject.callId,callId) = 0
```

its behaviour is ill-defined, because `callbackObject.callId` was never initialised. What happens then is that the ill-defined behaviour that you see is that the expression never evaluates to `True` and so you never assign to the `param` or `error` fields. Which is consistent with your observations.

I suspect that you should make `callId` be a `string` variable and copy into it the value of the parameter `callId` that was passed to `PConnect.callCustomfunction`. But since I don't know all the details of what you are doing, I can't be 100% sure of that.

Some other comments:

- Do you really mean to name your class `PConnect`? Normally we prefix classes with `T`.
- The code would read a lot easier if you used `for in` loops instead of `while` loops.
- The loop that contains a call to `Remove` on the list is inefficient. You've already found the item, and calling `Remove` just searches the list once again. The way to do that loop is with a class `for` loop using an index. And when you find the item to be deleted, call `Delete` passing the item's index.
- When you remove an item you fail to call `Dispose` which means that you leak memory.

Comment: 'fail to call Dispose' - 'free'.  You are into too many languages ;)

Comment: @MartinJames No. The memory was allocated by `New`. So it is deallocated with `Dispose`.

Comment: Oh yeah - good job I didn't downvote, that would have been even more embarrassing..

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for the accept. Would you be able to tell us what `CustomfunctionCallbackObject` is? I got a bit of flak in the comments for thinking it was a record. I'm curious to know!